# FFMPEG - The result of converting video to hevc format lost audio (video only)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, audio, hevc

I'm new in programming, I have some movies and want to convert them to hevc format to reduce storage space but keep quality video, i tried with my code through ffmpeg:

**`for %b in (*.mp4) DO ffmpeg -y -i "%b" -r 30 -g 50000 -q 22  -filter:v scale=650:-1 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -b:a 320k -ar 96000 -f hevc -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 10500k -strict experimental -shortest -x264-params -lossless 1 -tag:v hvc1 -movflags +faststart -threads 4 "output\%%~nb.hevc`

[Raw in pastebin](https://pastebin.com/raw/6HAurdFz"https://pastebin.com/raw/6HAurdFz")

(The directory I tested: [secufiles](https://secufiles.com/i54x/MyTest.rar"https://secufiles.com/i54x/MyTest.rar")!
)

I tried changing a lot of code but the result is still the same, the video only has images without sound, ffmpeg says me: "-qscale is ignored, -crf is recommended.", Please help me Or give me an idea for this code.

I am really grateful for any help from you.

Thank you very much.

Comment: See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265#ConstantRateFactorCRF

Answer (score 2):

There is so much wrong with your command that it would take too long to list every issue. It will be simplest to just provide a corrected command:

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx265 -crf 28 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -filter:v "scale=650:-2,format=yuv420p" -tag:v hvc1 -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

- If the input audio is already AAC consider stream copying with `-c:a copy` instead of re-encoding.
- Depending on the input format this may not be worth the time, energy, and effort. Results may not be satisfactory if you are re-encoding lossy content. The artifacts present in the input can complicate the compression and result in a higher than expected file size and/or lower than expected quality.

For more info see:

- [FFmpeg Wiki: H.265](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265)
- [FFmpeg Wiki: AAC](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC)